# Mongodb @DBRef query spring

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I my spring project, I am using two models with a reference.

A model user which has a reference on a token object.

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

   @Id
   public String id;
   @DBRef
   public Token token;
}
```

Then my Token object:

```
@Document(collection = "token")
public class Token {

   @Id
   public String id;
   public String token;
}
```

I am trying to query a user from a token.
I tried to create a MongoRepository interface :

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    @Query(value="{ 'token.id' : ?0 }")
    User findByTokenId(String id);
}
```

But that's not working. How can I create such kind or request ?

Comment: Can you add the sample doc that you are trying to query ?

Comment: User user = userRepository.findByTokenId(tokenFound.id);

Comment: Can you try 'token._id' ?

Comment: same error. I got an exception error. java.lang.NullPointerException: null. But my tokenFound object is valid

Comment: In my user object I have a token object with : { $ref, $id }

Comment: The data are well populated. The only issue is to query the user from a token.

Comment: I just tried a similar example it worked just fine. did you populate data using spring in the first place ? This is a my sample doc which I fetched. using `@Query(value="{ 'user.id' : ?0 }")`. `{ "_id" : "doc_user", "_class" : "com.mongodb.spring_mongo.DocumentFile", "user"
 : DBRef("User", "user") }` & `{ "_id" : "user", "_class" : "com.mongodb.spring_mongo.User", "name" : "userName
" }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132536/discussion-between-user2724028-and-sagar-reddy).

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    @Query(value="{ 'token.id' : ?0 }")
    User findAllByToken_Id(String id);
}
```